# Get Result from CompositeFuture Vertx

Tags: java, vert.x

I've recently learned about composite futures. I understand that i can have a list of Futures and when they are all completed, the compositeFuture handler will be called:

```
CompositeFuture.all(futures).onComplete(compositeAsync -> {
    if (compositeAsync.succeeded()){
        Future<CompositeFuture> cf = compositeAsync.result();
    } else {
        // at least 1 future failed
    }
});
```

My question is about this line: `Future<CompositeFuture> cf = compositeAsync.result();`

The futures that i passed into the compositeFuture is of type `List<Future<Buffer>>` however, the result() returns Future. How do i get the `Future<Buffer>` out of a `Future<CompoiteFuture>`?

I used the following example to pass in paramaterized futures into `compositeFuture.all(futures);`

```
interface MyCompositeFuture extends CompositeFuture {

    // This is what the regular does, just for example
    /*
    static CompositeFuture all(List<Future> futures) {
        return CompositeFutureImpl.all(futures.toArray(new Future[futures.size()]));
    }
    */

    static <T> CompositeFuture all(List<Future<T>> futures) {
        return CompositeFutureImpl.all(futures.toArray(new Future[futures.size()]));
    }
}
```

Source: [Vert.x java List<Futures> parameterization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467014/vert-x-java-listfutures-parameterization)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be getting the results, not the futures themselves:

```
CompositeFuture.all(futures).onComplete(compositeAsync -> {
    if (compositeAsync.succeeded()){
        CompositeFuture cf = compositeAsync.result();
        cf.list().forEach(futureResult -> {
            // do something with the result of each future
        });
    } else {
        // at least 1 future failed
    }
});
```

Note that `CompositeFuture extends Future<CompositeFuture>`, this is why your code works. But inside `onComplete` you should use it directly and not as a `Future<CompositeFuture>`